# Failed to access remote web service using javascript client

Tags: javascript, .net, json, web-services

I am trying to access .net webservice using javascript but gives me the following error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

here is java script code:

```
    var v = {"name":"zain",
            "password":"abc"
            }
 //           alert("wat");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "webcare.azurewebsites.net/WCService.asmx/GetParent",
                data: JSON.stringify(v),
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
                            });

        }
        function OnSuccess(data, status)
        {
           alert("success: "+data.d);
        }

        function OnError(request, status, error)
        {
            alert("error: "+request.statusText);
        }
```

aaccording to a solution which said to add a clientaccesspolicy.xml file alongside my web-service but its still giving the same error.
here is the code i added in clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Comment: Try `http://webcare.azurewebsites.net/WCService.asmx/GetParent` for the URL

Comment: Is it expecting a SOAP request (from the XML file)?  Because you are expecting the response to be JSON in your ajax call.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i added http:// now error has changed to: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: @dustmouse no it is expecting json result.

Comment: Server must allow CORS requests.  This is done using headers.

Comment: @Will how can i allow CORS requests in server?
my server is asp.net simple web service.

Comment: Dunno.  But that's what you need to research.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to have a cross domain xml file in the appropriate location https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx. Look for "To use a crossdomain.xml file to allow cross-domain access". Follow the instructions in that article.

Comment: i have done that too.
still getting `internet server error 500`